# Probability calculation for bayesian network

Tags: probability, bayesian-networks

I am struggling to understand how Bayesian probabilities are calculated for the following network:

[image]

I don't understand how the probability of 0.69 is calculated for the P(C=true|A=T)?

Also, how to calculate the initial probability of 0.19 for P(C=true) when there is no any evidence?

Comment: Good question. However Stackoverflow is for asking programming related questions. Please move it to Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/. If you think, however, this is programming related question then show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing a variable in the evidence, you need to sum over all the possible values of that variable (this is called marginalization).

```
P(C | A, B) = P(A, B, C) / P(A, B)

=>

P(C | A) = P (C, B=T | A) + P(C, B=F | A) 
         = P(C | B=T, A) * P(B=T | A) + P(C | B=F, A) * P(B=F | A)
```

And the same way if you want to have just `P(C)`.

See also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/268812/27854)

Comment: I'm missing something. From the probability tables, P(C|A)=0.9/0.55+0.45/0.45?

Comment: @hello What are you missing? The tables in your network are the probabilities `P(A)`, `P(B|A)` and `P(C|B,A)`.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to read from the tables, P(C | B=T, A) = 0.9, P(B=T | A)=0.55, P(C | B=F, A)=0.45 and P(B=F | A) =0.45? The result is not OK, so I'm doing smth wrong.

Comment: @hello Is State0 T of F?

Comment: I think I got the formula slightly wrong, I will check and edit if I find my error.

Comment: I got division and multiplication mixed up in the lower part of the equations. But I still get 0.425 instead of 0.69

Comment: State 0 is false. I've checked this network using the custom Python script I wrote using pomegranate package, as well as the Genie tool, and the correct probability is 0.69. You're right, =0.9*0.55+0.45*0.45 is OK. Thank you!

Comment: Still struggle to calculate P(C) without any evidences, the correct result is 0.19, please let me know if you get the numbers.

Comment: The nearly correct result: P(C)= P(C,A=T, B=T) + P(C,A=T, B=F) + P(C,A=F, B=T) + P(C,A=F, B=F) = 0.9*0.1*0.55+0.45*0.1*0.45+0.45*0.9*0.1+0.1*0.9*0.9 = 0.19